# JS Function return NaN

Tags: javascript, html, css, math, nan

I just made a question on this site, and received a perfect answer on how to do what i was trying to do (9 Button grid, 9 radio type grid, if i click a button i'll have on a div his value, if I also click a radio button, i'll have also another value based on a calculation.) The problem is that this function did not work with all button, but only with the first, so I tried to modify it in order to make it work with all the button, changing the value in the if and changing the variable to make the calculation. The fact is that the new part is perfectly functioning, but the original part that was working before, now give me NaN as the result of the calculation. I don't know how to solve this NaN or how to modify the original code, maybe the way i did is wrong and I could do it in an easyer way.

```js
/*
original function

var price;
        var stockT;
        var stock;
        var vol;

        document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(input){
            input.onclick = function() {
                price = this.value;
                document.querySelectorAll('.tabcosti .white')[1].innerText = price
            }
        })

        document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]').forEach(function(input) {
            input.onchange = function() {
                if (price == '1,56' && this.value == '4960') {
                stock = 0.00002;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,56' && this.value == '9900') {
                stock = 0.00002;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,56' && this.value == '14875') {
                stock = 0.00002;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,56' && this.value == '24800') {
                stock = 0.00002;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,56' && this.value == '35000') {
                stock = 0.00002;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,56' && this.value == '49200') {
                stock = 0.00002;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,56' && this.value == '74925') {
                stock = 0.00002;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,56' && this.value == '100000') {
                stock = 0.00002;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,56' && this.value == '150000') {
                stock = 0.00002;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                document.querySelectorAll('.tabcosti .white')[2].innerText = Math.round((stockT + Number.EPSILON) *100) / 100;
            };
            })*/




/*my try on making it work with all buttons*/

var price;
        var stockT;
        var stock;
        var vol;

        document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(input){
            input.onclick = function() {
                price = this.value;
                document.querySelectorAll('.tabcosti .white')[1].innerText = price
            }
        })

        document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]').forEach(function(input) {
            input.onchange = function() {
                if (price == '1,56' && this.value == '4960') {
                stock = 0.00002;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,56' && this.value == '9900') {
                stock = 0.00002;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,56' && this.value == '14875') {
                stock = 0.00002;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,56' && this.value == '24800') {
                stock = 0.00002;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,56' && this.value == '35000') {
                stock = 0.00002;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,56' && this.value == '49200') {
                stock = 0.00002;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,56' && this.value == '74925') {
                stock = 0.00002;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,56' && this.value == '100000') {
                stock = 0.00002;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,56' && this.value == '150000') {
                stock = 0.00002;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                document.querySelectorAll('.tabcosti .white')[2].innerText = Math.round((stockT + Number.EPSILON) *100) / 100;
            };

            input.onchange = function() {
                if (price == '1,04' && this.value == '4960') {
                stock = 0.000015;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,04' && this.value == '9900') {
                stock = 0.000015;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,04' && this.value == '14875') {
                stock = 0.000015;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,04' && this.value == '24800') {
                stock = 0.000015;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,04' && this.value == '35000') {
                stock = 0.000015;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,04' && this.value == '49200') {
                stock = 0.000015;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,04' && this.value == '74925') {
                stock = 0.000015;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,04' && this.value == '100000') {
                stock = 0.000015;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                if (price == '1,04' && this.value == '150000') {
                stock = 0.000015;
                vol = this.value;
                stockT = stock * vol;
                } else {
                vol = 1;
                }

                document.querySelectorAll('.tabcosti .white')[2].innerText = Math.round((stockT + Number.EPSILON) *100) / 100;
            };
            })
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.flex-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.justify {
  justify-content: center;
}

.align {
  align-items: center;
}

.evenly {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.m-0 {
  margin: 0;
}

.spacer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.orange {
  color: orange;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bg {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.tabtitle {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tariffe {
  font-size: small;
}

.intro {
  text-align: center;
}

.tartitle {
  font-size: medium;
}

div h2 {
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.cont {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cont2 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.m-7 {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.m-14 {
  margin: 14px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div input {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

div input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.richiedi {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 50px;
}

.tabcosti {
  background-color: darkorange;
  border: solid darkorange 1px;
}

.border {
  border: solid darkorange 1px;
}

.black {
  color: black;
}

.white {
  color: white;
}

.m-left-50 {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.x-small {
  font-size: x-small;
}

.tabcosti2 {
  border-top: 0px;
  border: solid darkorange 1px;
}

.margin-left {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.info {
  width: 215px;
  height: 20px;
}

.info2 {
  width: 75px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.small {
  font-size: small;
}

.unbtn {
  border: 0px;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.unbtn:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: white;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.btn {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 184px;
  height: 40px;
}

.btn2 {
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 184px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="button-container" class="justify evenly flex-row">
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <button id="sel" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,56">Abbigliamento e Scarpe</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <button id="sel2" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,04">Pet & Food</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <button id="sel3" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,30">Sport e Tempo libero</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <button id="sel4" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,04">Elettronica e Informatica</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <button id="sel5" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,04">Casa e Cucina</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <button id="sel6" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,30">Auto e Moto</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <button id="sel7" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,17">Food & Beverage</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <button id="sel8" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,30">Belleza e Salute</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>




<div id="radio" class="justify m-30 evenly flex-row bg">
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="31x16x10"> 31x16x10
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="33x20x15"> 33x20x15
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="35x25x17"> 35x25x17
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="40x31x20"> 40x31x20
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="40x35x25"> 40x35x25
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="41x40x30"> 41x40x30
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="45x45x37"> 45x45x37
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="50x50x40"> 50x50x40
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="60x50x50"> 60x50x50
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="radio2" class="flex-row bg m-7 justify evenly">
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="0-1 kg" name="Peso"> 0-1 kg
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="1-2 kg" name="Peso"> 1-2 kg
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="2-3 kg" name="Peso"> 2-3 kg
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="3-5 kg" name="Peso"> 3-5 kg
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="5-7 kg" name="Peso"> 5-7 kg
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="7-10 kg" name="Peso"> 7-10 kg
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="10-15 kg" name="Peso"> 10-15 kg
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="15-20 kg" name="Peso"> 15-20 kg
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="20-30 kg" name="Peso"> 20-30 kg
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="justify evenly flex-row">
  <div class="flex-col">
    <p>TARIFFA DI GESTIONE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <p>TARIFFA DI RESO</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <p>TARIFFA DI STOCCAGGIO</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tabcosti evenly justify flex-row">
  <div class="flex-col">
    <p id="reso">€ <span class="white"></span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <p>€ <span class="white"></span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <p>€ <span class="white"></span> <span class="x-small">al mese</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know you cannot see the formula for the calculation, it's because i have all the data in an excel file, but the function already have it, the number i used are all in this file

Comment: btw, why do you use strings for numerical values?

Comment: because i'm dumb and i forgot to change it :')

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. It was incredibly dumb.
I just needed tu place "};" this at the end all together with the other of the other button function.